# Making tawba while menstruating

Tags: forgiveness, tawba

I did something which I regret doing but I’m not able to pray since I’m on my period. How can I make tawba?

Answer (score 1):

One does tawbah by feeling remorse with their heart, seeking forgiveness verbally from Allah and firmly intending to never repeat the sin. It is not necessary to perform ritual salah for it to be valid.